# How to align ReactJS's <button/> and <input/> in same row/horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, reactjs

I have `<button/>` and `<input/>` inside a container. How can I get them to align in the same row and in the middle of the container vertically (`<div className="container">`)?

This is what I have so far:

```
<div className="container">
   <div>
     <input className="form-control" placeholder='Enter Email'/>
   </div>
   <div>
     <button type="submit" className="btn"> Register </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

With className="container":

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 137px;
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried what you suggested with the following but the `<input/>` and `<button/>` is still on top of each other:

[image]

The top black portion is a navigation bar and I want to align everything inside the bar horizontally, next to each other from left to right.

```
       <div className="container">
          <h1>
            TESTING
          </h1>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            id="input-field"
            placeholder='Enter Email'
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn"
          >
            Register
          </button>
      </div>
```

Comment: These are very basic html5/css questions. Nothing to do with reactjs really.  I suggest you study up a bit on these topics

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex-box for this. 
Swap out the `class` attribute for `className` in react

**edit:**
To answer your edited question:

- align everything horizontally with `align-items: center` on the flex container
- Ensure the `input` and `button` don't break into separate lines by wrapping them together in a container element.

```css
h1 { color: white; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #222;
}

.email-holder {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>TESTING</h1>
  <div class="email-holder">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder='Enter Email'/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn"> Register </button>
  <div/>  
</div>
```

Comment: forgot to mention but there is also going on the left side and the text input with button on the right, with some distance in between left and right. How should I style the < img > and also to make the container itself resize, even if the window gets too small, don't make them overlap each other?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've my previous comment. Please let me know!

Comment: I made the attempt that you suggested but still does not work properly. I updated the original post. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, been busy, I'll take a look now

Comment: No worries! Looking forward to it and thank you so much!

Comment: Checking in to see if you had the chance. Thank you!

Comment: This solution does not work for me. It aligns the heading (h1) and the button below each other and not horizontally beside each other.